# Visual Studio - automatically add necessary spaces to comments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ide

When I'm writing comments in my code, I often forget to add the initial space after the comment identifier.

> 'this is a comment

when really it is supposed to be

> ' this is a comment

I realize this is quite trivial, and you could simply say "just add the damn space you idiot", but I'd really like to automate this so that I just don't have to worry about it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of an elegant way to add the comment space?

***note*** I do realize that a catch all string replace or regex replace could screw up other things ... IE:

> Dim something As String = "I'm a nerd"

would actually come out

> Dim something As String = "I' m a nerd"

So the way I see this being resolved is if it's only on a line by it's self and is not followed by a second single quote... IE: `''` would not trigger the replacement.

Comment: I think you are being obsessive/compulsive. :O) I actually like no space.

Comment: Note that the space/lack of is normally used to differentiate a comment and commented code. C# code normally uses `// ` and `////`, with `//` being ambigious.

Answer (score 2):

You could always get a copy of resharper and one of the rules in there is what you are describing. Once you finish with your code you can do a format on the whole file or even solution and it will globally fix that rule for you.

Comment: I actually have resharper... I'm more so wondering about doing this on the fly (real time)

Comment: I can't find this feature in the VB.NET version of ReSharper

Answer (score 1):

This would be a pretty good case for an editor extension. You can detect when a line is whitespace, apostrophe, not white space and either insert the space or put a decoration so you will learn to follow the pattern. If you've moved to 2010, consider it - they are really pretty easy to write.

Comment: do you have references I can look at? I think this might not be a bad idea.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/WriteExtensions.aspx is a train-the-trainer for those who want to deliver a one hour talk on editor extensions. You can use the demo script and code to help you get started. http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VSIPMarketing/VSX103-Lighting-up-the-new-Visual-Studio-2010-Editor-with-Rich-Extensions/ is a presentation from the VSX folks that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had and have similiar problems. This is a habit which you can change. Yet, sometimes your brain is just wired to make the same mistakes. For instance, no matter what I do, I ***always*** type `data` instead of `date`.

You can change your behavior. Find some method that you find helpful for changing habits. Create a "personal code review" checklist and add this item. After a few months, you will find the space comes naturally.

If this is one of the "hard-wired" brain goofs, then create a *Visual Studio" macro that visit's CodeDom. Through the `CodeDom` namespace it is easy to find comments and make changes as needed. Why use regular-expressions?

If you want to use regular-expressions, because you are familiar and it is easier, then create a better expression to avoid potential errors.

*Refactoring VB.NET code with regular expressions* at http://www.vbmigration.com/Blog/post/2008/07/Refactoring-VB%2cNET-code-with-regular-expressions.aspx should be helpful in creating better regular-expressions.

Comment: I am working on breaking the habit, but it's a hard one to break.